# What short story is about changing humanity into a hive mind?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

An alien lands on Earth and is amazed that this species has come this far with all those separate minds. He decides to unite them and rule them. The hive mind that originates from this successfully conquers the alien.
It was written in the 70's or 80's.

The transformation of the human race is done on a telepathic level and is instantaneous. I remember mankind fights back by cooperating on a astonishing way, a woman even offers her child since it is the perfect fit to obstruct some of the alien machinery.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct, click on the check mark next to it (you should now be able to do it). Since you haven't registered, you'll only be able to access this account as long as you keep your browser cookie, barring moderator intervention. I suggest [registering](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/login) to [be able to use the site fully](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account).

Answer (score 15):

This is a good match for [*The Cosmic Rape*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cosmic_Rape), also [published](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9627) as [*To Marry Medusa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cosmic_Rape), by [Theodore Sturgeon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Sturgeon), except that this story was published in 1958. You may have known it only from one of the later reprints or from its alternate title.

Medusa is an interstellar hive mind. She intends to absorb Earth (humans) as she has absorbed many other worlds. And while she does succeed in transforming humanity into a hive mind, that mind defeats her.

If that's not the story you were thinking of, its author had probably read *The Cosmic Rape*.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, but that is not the one. I do not remember ever having read Sturgeon. The transformation of the human race is done on a telepathic level and is instantaneous. I remember mankind fights back by cooperating on a astonishing way, a woman even offers her child since it is the perfect fit to obstruct some of the alien machinery.

Comment: @Richard: You should have included those details in your question, and you can edit it even now. However, these details only confirm my answer. Mankind indeed astonishes Medusa by overcooperating, and the detail about the child is 40 minutes after humanity's conversion, in chapter 25.

Comment: In _The Cosmic Rape / To Marry Medusa_, the part of the hive mind is first absorbed by a drunkard, who ingested it by eating a hamburger. He is the only one **not** affected by it and is afterwards rewarded by (the now united) humanity, by keeping him perpetually happy, sort of like in the song "Big Rock Candy Mountains".